# Iteration error showing while using google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am encountering the following issue:
I am trying to grab the users that are within x [miles/km] from the user’s cell
phone.  I am using the datastore api for google app engine, I cant figure out
what is the problem. The issue is that when i fetch the record using the
itiration – an error appears telling me i cant use diffeant properties in the 
combination filter.

```
    package com.linkedlive.business;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.biomedica.server.geolocation.GeoLocation;
    import com.biomedica.server.searchtools.SearchForGeolocEntitiy;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Venue extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        this.doPost(req, resp);

    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        DatastoreService datastore =
      DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();


        String cmd=req.getParameter("cmd");
        if(cmd.equals("venuenearby"))
        {
            GeoLocation geo=new GeoLocation();
            SearchForGeolocEntitiy search=new
    SearchForGeolocEntitiy("accounts");// this is a class that i created to set the
    query filters see bellow
            // get request parameters
            float lat=Float.valueOf(req.getParameter("lat"));
            float lng=Float.valueOf(req.getParameter("lng"));
            float rad=Float.valueOf(req.getParameter("rad"));
            // calculate the distance


            Iterable<Entity>
    ent=search.GetJSONForEntitiyNearByUsingBounds(lat,
    lng,geo.getGeoLocationBounds(lat, lng, rad) );
            Iterator<Entity> i=ent.iterator();
            JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
            JSONArray injson=new JSONArray();
            json.put("result", "venuenearby");

            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
                    Entity t=i.next();
                    j.put("key",
    KeyFactory.keyToString(t.getKey()));
                    j.put("userid",
    t.getProperty("userid"));
                    j.put("filepath",
    t.getProperty("filepath"));
                    injson.put(j);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            json.put("body",injson);
            resp.getWriter().write(json.toString());
        }


    }
    }





///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////
//////////////////////////  SearchForGeolocEntitiy      
////////////////////////////////////


    package com.biomedica.server.searchtools;

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import com.biomedica.server.geolocation.GeoLocation;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilterOperator;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterPredicate;
    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilter;

     public class SearchForGeolocEntitiy {
     private String EntitiyName;
     private Query q;

     public SearchForGeolocEntitiy(String name)
    {
        EntitiyName=name;
        q=new Query(name);

    }
    public Iterable<Entity> GetJSONForEntitiyNearBy(double lang,double
    lat,double rad,int max_result)
    {
        DatastoreService datastore =
    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        // decleeraing filter object




                Filter filter_min_lngt=new
    FilterPredicate("lng", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, lang-rad);
                Filter filter_max_lngt=new
    FilterPredicate("lng", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, lang+rad);
                Filter filter_min_lat=new
    FilterPredicate("lat", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, lat-rad);
                Filter filter_max_lat=new
    FilterPredicate("lat", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, lat+rad);

                Filter filter_lng=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_min_lngt,filte
    r_max_lngt));
                Filter filter_lat=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_min_lat,filter
    _max_lat));


                Filter filter=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_lng,filter_lat
     ));

                q.setFilter(filter);
                PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);


                return pq.asIterable();

    }
    public Iterable<Entity> GetJSONForEntitiyNearByUsingSSID(String
    EntityName,String entityID,String SSID)
    {
        DatastoreService datastore =
    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        // decleeraing filter object


            Filter filter_entityID=new FilterPredicate(EntityName,
    FilterOperator.EQUAL, entityID);

                Filter filter_min_lngt=new
    FilterPredicate("lng", FilterOperator.EQUAL, SSID);

                Filter filter=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_entityID,filte
    r_min_lngt));

                q.setFilter(filter);

                PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
                return pq.asIterable();


    }
    public Iterable<Entity> GetJSONForEntitiyNearByUsingBounds(float
    lng,float lat,GeoLocation.GeoLocationBoundry bound)
    {
        DatastoreService datastore =
    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

        Filter filter_min_lngt=new FilterPredicate("lng",
    FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, bound.lng1);
        Filter filter_max_lngt=new FilterPredicate("lng",
    FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, bound.lng2);
        Filter filter_min_lat=new FilterPredicate("lat",
    FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, bound.lat1);
        Filter filter_max_lat=new FilterPredicate("lat",
    FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, bound.lat2);

        Filter filter_lng=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_min_lngt,filte
    r_max_lngt));
        Filter filter_lat=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_min_lat,filter
    _max_lat));


        Filter filter=new
    CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND,Arrays.asList(filter_lng,filter_lat
    ));

        q.setFilter(filter);

        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);


        return pq.asIterable();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting a limitation of the datastore.  Inequality filters can only be on one property.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries

The easiest way around this is to use the Search API.  Otherwise, you need to build your own geohashing like mechanism to search within a range without using multiple inequality filters.